# How to redirect to standard page?

Tags: apex, button-overrides

This is the class:

```
public class overrideButtonExtension 
{ 
    //public string callfunc{get;set;}   
    //public Task t {get; set;}
    //Public Account acc{get;set;}
     PageReference pageRef;
    public Opportunity opp{get;set;}
    public Id opid {get; set;}

    public overrideButtonExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {

        //acc = NEW Account(); 
        PageReference pageRef;
        opp = NEW Opportunity(); 
        opid = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('what_Id');

        System.debug('/////////////'+ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters());
        opp =  [SELECT Name, AccountId, Account.Name FROM Opportunity WHERE Id =:opid ];
        //acc = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Id=:opp.AccountId];

        System.debug('/////////////'+opp);

               /*if(opp.Account.Name == 'ACME')
               {                           
                   ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.WARNING,'Task cant be generated'));

               }
               else
               {
                   openTask();
               }*/

               //openTask();

     }
       public PageReference openTask()
       {

           /*String sfdcURL = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() ; */
           if(opp.Account.Name == 'ACME')
               {                           
                   ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.WARNING,'Task is already Exist for this account'));
                   return null;
               }
               else
               {
                   pageRef = NEW PageReference('https://ap2.salesforce.com/00T/e?what_id='+opid+'&retURL=%2F00628000008ysV6');
                   System.debug('/////////////'+pageref); 
                   return pageRef;
               }   



       }
}
```

Here in that else part the url is contineously redirecting.I need to redirect the Task standard page after clicking New Task button.

Please help me out

Comment: what do you mean that it is 'contineously redirecting'? Is it not landing on to the redirected URL or is it stuck in URL redirection ?

Comment: it is stuck in url

Comment: Try setting pageRef.setRedirect(False);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appending:

```
&nooverride=1
```

to the URL should give you the standard Salesforce page.

**PS**

On Adrian's point, hard coding the instance into your code means the code won't work should your org be moved (which happens occasionally to redistribute load) and also won't work in a sandbox. So better to use relative URLs i.e. `new PageReference('/00T/e?what_id...')`.

Comment: Can you mention why it's bad practice to construct a url bound to a specific instance (`ap2`) and how to fix it?